# Tcl global variables in proc declaration

Tags: tcl

So I have this piece of Tcl code that inherited. Essentially it does the following:

```
set LOG_ALL     0
set LOG_DEBUG   1
set LOG_INFO    2
set LOG_WARN    3
set LOG_ERROR   4
set LOG_FATAL   5
set LOG_SILENT  6

proc v2 {vimm {log LOG_DEBUG}} {
    global LOG_DEBUG
    if {$log == $LOG_DEBUG} {
        puts "log"
    } else {
        puts "no log"
    }
}
```

I suspect that the original idea of the designed was to use global variable for the default value of the **log** parameter. However, it isn't working as expected and I can't find how to write it correctly, assuming it even possible.

Which syntax will be correct?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this would be correct:

```
proc v2 [list vimm [list log $LOG_DEBUG]] {
    # ... body same as before
}
```

But that's just ugly. A neater way is:

```
proc v2 {vimm {log ""}} {  # Any dummy value would do...
    global LOG_DEBUG
    if {[llength [info level 0]] < 3} {
        set log $LOG_DEBUG
    }
    # ... as before
}
```

But the true Zen of Tcl is to not use numbers for this task at all, but rather names:

```
proc v2 {vimm {log "debug"}} {
    if {$log eq "debug"} {
        puts "log"
    } else {
        puts "no log"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need numeric comparisons, use symbolic names. If you do, use an array to map the symbolic names into numbers just for the comparison. Symbols are what you really mean, so write exactly that!

Comment: So you are basically suggest to use strings (the third example). I'm not sure about the amount of changes it will require. I'd rather stick with numbers, if possible.
How does your first example work exactly?

Comment: The first example constructs the nested list structure that is the argument descriptor using the `list` command instead of using a literal. The second example works by introspecting on the list of actual arguments with `info level 0`. The third example is about changing the game; I don't really expect you to go with that one, to be honest. :–) _I_ mostly prefer the second one, as that also allows a dynamically-calculated default, but there's nothing wrong with the first.